# loop to replace copy in paragraph is not working

Tags: javascript, loops

I would like to replace the word 'copy' in the paragraph below with 'text', without using the JS "replace" method. Any ideas why my solution is not working? Any help is highly appreciated.

```
<p id="paragraph1">"Automated Copy Testing is a specialized type of digital marketing specifically related to digital advertising. This involves using software to deploy copy variations of digital advertisements ...."</p>

<button id="btn-1" type="button" onclick="changetext()">Change Copy!</button>

<script>
function changetext() {
var i;
var content = document.getElementById("paragraph1").innerHTML;
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
if (content.slice(i, i + 4) === "copy") {
    content = content.slice(0, i) + "text" + content.slice(i + 4); 
}
document.getElementById("copy2").innerHTML = content;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {` Who is `text`? Did you mean `content` ? Also you have some syntax errors (missing `}` from the `function`. Make sure you check your browser console for errors.

Comment: Proper indentation can solve most missing `{}` issues.

Comment: Aside from the bracket issues that others have pointed out.  I'd like to suggest your code and the other answers advance i (ie. i += 3) if the loop finds the word copy.  There's no point in testing for copy in the next few characters if we know it's going to be text.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, a missing bracket was the start, as well as `text` not being defined. If you fix those, you get:

```
function changetext() {
    var i;
    var content = document.getElementById("paragraph1").innerHTML;
    for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        if (content.slice(i, i + 4) === "copy") {
            content = content.slice(0, i) + "text" + content.slice(i + 4); 
        }
        document.getElementById("copy2").innerHTML = content;
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
"Automated Copy Testing is a specialized type of digital marketing specifically related to digital advertising. This involves using software to deploy text variations of digital advertisements ...."
```

Which is fine and all, but if you want to catch the first "Copy", try using the `toLowerCase()` method:

```
function changetext() {
    var i;
    var content = document.getElementById("paragraph1").innerHTML;
    for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        if (content.slice(i, i + 4).toLowerCase() === "copy") {
            content = content.slice(0, i) + "text" + content.slice(i + 4); 
        }
        document.getElementById("copy2").innerHTML = content;
    }
}
```

Which gives us:

```
"Automated text Testing is a specialized type of digital marketing specifically related to digital advertising. This involves using software to deploy text variations of digital advertisements ...."
```

Answer (score 0):

Various reasons why your code is not working.

1) Your code is missing closing `}`'s

2) `for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {` 
    
should be
 
   `for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {`

3) your paragraph contains `"Copy"` and you are comparing your content only with `"copy"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var content = document.getElementById("paragraph1").innerHTML;
  var replace_copy_to_text = content.split('copy').join('text');
```

This is case sensitive replacement and only replace lowercase "copy" not "Copy"